# How to match subdirectories in RewriteCond?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

Having trouble with proper regex for RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
```

Works as expected, that is, does not apply following rewrite to all URLs that start with /foo/.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/bar/
```

On the other hand does not work as I expect. URLs that begin with /foo/bar/ are still being rewrited.

How do I enter proper regex for excluding subdirectories?

Comment: How do the actual rules look like?

Comment: It should work. Could you set a RewriteLog with a RewriteLogLevel of at least 3 and add it to your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe it’s the new URL of an internal redirect the rule is applied to. The [`L` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does that.

> […] if the `RewriteRule` generates an internal redirect (which frequently occurs when rewriting in a per-directory context), this will reinject the request and will cause processing to be repeated starting from the first `RewriteRule`.

If you want to make sure that the initial URL path didn’t start with „/foo/bar“, check the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) (see [`THE_REQUEST` variable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)) instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /foo/bar/
RewriteRule …
```

Comment: @Gumbo: could you please exactly explain the regexp you used in your suggestion? It works for me too, and I guess it matches the first GET, but can't understand the subsequent '/' and the reason why there's no domain before '/foo/bar/'

Comment: @Stratboy I’ve hoped the linked pages explain everything. Well, the pattern `^[A-Z]+\ /foo/bar/` checks the HTTP request line as seen by the server’s HTTP parser and the condition is only true when the pattern is not matched. Maybe it’s the `\ ` that distracts you but that is still part of the pattern.

Comment: wow - no idea why %{REQUEST_URI} fails for me - however your solution is working. Thank you!