# Apache mod_rewrite - Redirect to HTTPS except one friendly URL (Controller)

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a website that needs to force HTTPS except when a particular URL begins with a pattern.

The problem is I have a redirection to index.php to load a PHP Controller in my system. When it redirects to index.php rewrite rules are applied again but %{REQUEST_URI} becomes index.php after the redirection and URL that can use http is redirected to https.

Is there a way around that ? Maybe not reading the rules again after internal redirection or keeping REQUEST_URI the same.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ok_with_http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`%{THE_REQUEST}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) could be used instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` to test the original request even after internal redirect to `index.php`.

According to the manual:

> **THE_REQUEST**
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1`). This does not include any
>   additional headers sent by the browser. This value has not been
>   unescaped (decoded), unlike most other variables below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /ok_with_http(/\S*)?\s
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/839837/3549014) that I used as a reference.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed this variable, it works as expected. Take my points! :)

Comment: Thank you, your solution helped me a lot